# Como mudar o TYPE de um input sem usar o valor de value com Java script?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte select

Quero mudar o TYPE e o placeholder do input sem utilixar o value do option, pois uso esse valor em um função em PHP, porem não sei como fazer de outra forma sem modificar o value.

Ja tentei criar atributo personalizado no option, como `tipodetype="number"` ou `novodeplaceholder="Coloque aqui seu numero com +55"` mas sempre da erro.

```html
<select name="tipodechave" class="form-select" id="selecao" required>
  <option value="">Selecione o tipo de chave</option>
  <option value="1">Telefone (utilizar o +55 antes do número.)</option>
  <option value="2">Email</option>
  <option value="3">CPF (Utilizar somente números.)</option>
  <option value="4">CNPJ (Utilizar somente números.)</option>
  <option value="5">Chave Aleatória</option>
</select>


<script>
  var selecao, mudar;
  selecao = document.getElementById("selecao");
  selecao.addEventListener("change", function() {
  mudar = document.getElementById("chave").type = selecao.value
  });
</script>


<input class="form-control" type="text" id="chave" name="chave" placeholder="Informe a chave pix" value="<?= $chave_pix; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" onclick="this.select();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Leia as informações acima para não fazer errado." required>
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu faria algo como uma lista de inputs baseados nos inputs que você quer ao invés de mudar o type dele, e adicionaria ao HTML do container o input correto

```js
    <select name="tipodechave" class="form-select" id="selecao" required>
      <option value="0">Selecione o tipo de chave</option>
      <option value="1">Telefone (utilizar o +55 antes do número.)</option>
      <option value="2">Email</option>
      <option value="3">CPF (Utilizar somente números.)</option>
      <option value="4">CNPJ (Utilizar somente números.)</option>
      <option value="5">Chave Aleatória</option>
    </select>

    <div class="inputcontainer"></div>

    <script>
      const selecao = document.getElementById('selecao');

      const inputs = [
        `<input placeholder='0'/>`,
        `<input placeholder='1'/>`,
        `<input placeholder='2'/>`
      ];

      selecao.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        const container = document.querySelector('.inputcontainer');

        container.innerHTML = inputs[e.target.value];
      });
    </script>
```